# Split Variable Pairs into Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2022

Using SQL Server 2022, I'm trying to figure out how to use `STRING_SPLIT` in a set-based way to convert a table column where all rows have a variable number of key/value pairs into a table without duplicates, similar to [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) but not quite.

```
create table #mashed (mashedtext nvarchar(1600))

insert into #mashed 
values ('"id":"one", "code":"aaa", "dev":"yes"')
insert into #mashed 
values ('"id":"two", "code":"bbb", "dev":"yes"')
insert into #mashed 
values ('"id":"three", "code":"ccc", "dev":"no"')
insert into #mashed 
values ('"id":"three", "code":"bbb", "help":"no" , "rid":"6"')
```

Desired shape of output

```
   key    value
----------------
   id     one
   id     two
   id     three
   code   aaa
   code   bbb
   code   ccc
   dev    yes
   dev    no
   help   no
   rid    6
```

This is clearly wrong:

```
SELECT value 
FROM STRING_SPLIT (SELECT mashedtext FROM #mashed, ',')
```

So what is the right way to do this without RBAR? I am sure there are two splits needed, once to get the pairs and again on each pair.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a comma between `"bbb"` and `help"` (`"code":"bbb" "help":"no"`)? The idea is to parse the text as JSON: `SELECT DISTINCT j.[key], j.[value] FROM #mashed m CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('{', m.mashedtext, '}')) j`

Comment: @Zhorov yes I was missing comma, now editing original q to include it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stored text data is almost a valid JSON object, so you may try to fix it and parse it with `OPENJSON()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT j.[key], j.[value]
FROM #mashed m
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('{', m.mashedtext, '}')) j
```

If you want to use `STRING_SPLIT()` you need to use the third optional parameter in `STRING_SPLIT()` (introduced in SQL Server 2022) to get the ordinal position of the each substring:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s2.*
FROM #mashed m
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(m.mashedtext, ',') s1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT
      [key] = MAX (REPLACE(CASE WHEN [ordinal] = 1 THEN [value] END, '"', '')),
      [value] = MAX (REPLACE(CASE WHEN [ordinal] = 2 THEN [value] END, '"', ''))
  FROM STRING_SPLIT(TRIM(s1.[value]), ':', 1)
) s2
```

Result (without order):

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| code | aaa |
| code | bbb |
| code | ccc |
| dev | no |
| dev | yes |
| help | no |
| id | one |
| id | three |
| id | two |
| rid | 6 |

Comment: Winning! Is there a smart way to index within the mashedtext column? On a table with 250k rows it takes 13 seconds, this table will have 5m rows at full at runtime. Even if it negatively impact insert performance, extraction speed will be critical.

Comment: It turns out some of the keys in the real data set have colons in the key so they look like  ....values ('"id":"three:six:nine", "code":"ccc", "dev":"no"')... and some values also have colons and commas, am struggling with converting the inner separators to slashes, what is best way to update that?

Comment: @Snowy, I think the JSON-based approach solves this issue and returns `id` as `key` and `three:six:nine` as `value` (using test data `"id":"three:six:nine", "code":"ccc", "dev":"no"`).

Answer (score 1):

`STRING_SPLIT()` to split into rows and then perform string parsing to extract the required `key` and `value`

```
SELECT m.mashedtext, v.[value], kv.[key], kv.[val]
FROM   #mashed m
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(mashedtext, ',') s
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           -- remove leading spaces
           select [value] = ltrim(s.[value])
       ) v
       CROSS APPLY
       (     
           -- find position of colon
           select p = charindex(':', v.[value])
       ) p
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           -- get the required key and val
           select [key] = replace(left(v.value, p - 1), '"', ''),
                  [val] = replace(right(v.value, len(v.value) - p), '"', '')
       ) kv
```